# Invalid Label in Object Javascript- Want to add event Listner

Tags: javascript, label, addeventlistener

```
({
photo:  foo.addEventListener("animationend", photoCycle, true) ||  foo.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", photoCycle, true),

bio: foo.addEventListener("animationend", bioCycle, true) ||  foo.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", bioCycle, true)
})[mode]
```

I am trying to make an object to evaluate mode(which will ether be  strings `photo` or `bio`) and add an event listener according to whether it is firefox `animationend` or chrome `webkitanimationend`. Strangely, when mode is `photo` I get a syntax error for invalid label for the `bio` key.

Answer (score 1):

This construct is assigning value to unnamed object properties. Also the or method to select the right event name will not work as addEventListener is a valid function on both browser.

Here is some code to do this:

```
var fn = (mode == "photo") ? photoCycle : bioCycle;
var eventName = ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("WebKit") != -1) ? "webkitAnimationEnd" : "animationEnd";

foo.addEventListener(eventName, bioCycle, true)
```